# Rails many-to-many assignment with unique DB entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, many-to-many

I'm running a Rails 5.2.1 app, with Ruby 2.6.7.

I have a Forum-like app, and I'm trying to implement a home-baked Tagging system, similar to what StackOverflow has. The way I chose to do it, is to have a simple join table that will facilitate a `has_many through:` relationship for my `Tag` and `Question` models.

The problem I'm encountering is that I'm not sure how to assign a Tag to a question without creating a new entry in the Tag table (assuming this is even possible to do). Preferably, I'd want the database to only have 1 entry for each unique tag.

For example, when a new question is created, a user would select a tag which already exists, and the question would be linked to the specific ID of the tag in question.

- User creates question, with `id: 1`, chooses tag that in the DB has `id: 1`
- In the Join table, this would look like `question_id: 1 | tag_id: 1`
- User creates another question, now with `id: 2`, and again chooses tag `id: 1`
- The table for that has `question_id: 2 | tag_id: 1`

As it is right now, if I do `question.tags.create(id: 1)`, the tag doesn't get created. On the other hand, if I do `question.tags.create(name: "tagname")`, the tag does get created, but it's created as a new Tag entry and has `id: 2`, leaving me with two tags with the same name.

My models:

```rb
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :question_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :question_tags
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :question_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, through: :question_tags
end

class QuestionTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

How could I achieve the result I want? Presumably, I'd use some sort of `before_Save` or `before_create` hook to handle it for me, but I'm unsure of how exactly to implement that properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could find all the Tag ids from the user's selection and then just add those. ActiveRecord gives you `#tag_ids`. In your service or controller or w/e, you could just add them there; ie select the tags for the question, get the id from the select value, in your controller permit the tag_ids and then assign as needed.

```rb
# form
<%= select question[tag_ids][], .... %>

# controller

private

def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:id, ..., tag_ids: [])
end

# Then used similarly whereever you choose
question = Question.find(params[:id])
question.tag_ids << question_params[:tag_ids]
or
question.tag_ids = question_params[:tag_ids]

You can create/update a question with the tag_ids like any attribute
```